# Can a polynomial composition be written as a product of a polynomial over linear factors?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I recently deleted this same question, because i thought i had solved it, but I didn't, and its proving very tricky:

Find a polynomial $u_f\in\mathbb{C}[x]$  such that, for any two given $ f,g\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$, $g(x)=\alpha(x-\theta_0)(x-\theta_1)$, $\mathrm{Deg}(f,g)=(n,2)$ we have that:
$$f(g(x))=u_f(x-\theta_0)u_f(x-\theta_1)$$
Otherwise, prove $u_f$ doesn't exist.

I've found some numerical examples of polynomials $t≈u_f$ (the approximation is sharp) and cases where this same approximation is apparently unreachable. Maybe this is a matter of the specific nature of $f$ and $g$? If so, it should be possible to show $u_f$ doesn't exist!

---

**For insight:**

One of my primary objectives is to show that a certain kind of polynomial transformation is possible. There are many ways to do this, but one of the cleanest ways to do so is by showing the statement above, or some version of it. As an example: if we know that a polynomial $e(x)=r(x+a)r(x+b)$, $a,b\in \mathbb{C}$, shows $e\in\mathbb{R}[x]$, then we'll have that $a=\overline{b}$ for every $r\in\mathbb{R}[x]$ (this follows from several field-theoretic theorems). One easy way to prove this would be by finding the transformation $u_r\in\mathbb{R}[x]$ that satisfies:
$$e(x)=u_r((x+a)(x+b))$$
and showing that the fairly simpler polynomial $(x+a)(x+b)$ must be in $\mathbb{R}[x]$.
This is the exact opposite case from the one in the question, but entails a similar problem. Morover, the above statement could serve as an induction step for more complicated cases.

Comment: So $u_f$ doesn't depend on $f$?

Comment: Its more or less a type of polynomial transformation from $f$ to $u_f$ and viceversa. I'll add more details in an edit.

Comment: The way you wrote it, $f$ was quantified *after* $u_f$, so it reads like the same $u_f$ should work for all $f$.